# How to design Hadoop job to match fields from one file to another

Tags: hadoop

I have two different files which each contain different data. I would like to do some processing with these files then merge the data together based on matching keys. What is the best way to implement this in Hadoop? I was thinking of somehow creating two mappers that would each process one file then a reducer to combine the data? I'm not sure if this is even possible. Does anyone have any suggestion as to how I can combine data from two files in Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to write map/reduce job (Hive, Pig, Cascading, Java etc.) but essentially a join is a multi-input job where the mappers emit record in the key_to_join_by and rest_of_data format and the reducer does the actual join (unless one of the files is small enough to hold in memory where you can do the join in the mapper)

You can see an example of how to do this in Pig [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#join-inner)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give examples of your file? It is not clear what you are asking. Are you talking about doing joins in Hadoop? If so you will need to have two mapper classes. Or you can use Hive which makes performing joins easier. Please look at this for examples of both the possible solutions: [Joins in Hadoop](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html)